Ensure consistent data in a pair of columns between two tables
The locations table looks like below. Note that sometimes, multiple locations can share the same equipment (both L1 and L2 use E1).



Location_id
Equipment_id




L1
E1


L2
E1


L3
E2


L4
E3



The messages table looks like below. Each equipment will have multiple messages. In instances where locations share equipment, different messages will correspond to different locations (For E1, M1 and M2 are related to L1, but M3 is related to L2).



Equipment_id
Message_id
Location_id




E1
M1
L1


E1
M2
L1


E2
M3
L2


E2
M1
L3


E2
M2
L3


E3
M1
L4


E3
M2
L4



What is the proper way to ensure that data in the two tables will not be inconsistent with the relationship between Location_id and Equipment_id? I don't want the messages table to have a pair that is not present in the locations table, and vice versa. Do I need additional table to enforce the behavior?

I don't want the messages table to have a pair that is not present in the locations table ALTER TABLE messages ADD FOREIGN KEY (Location_id, Equipment_id) REFERENCES locations (Location_id, Equipment_id);. Do not forget to create all needed indices. and vice versa - impossible in MySQL/MariaDB, except trigger logic usage.

The vica-versa will have a chicken-or-egg problem: when you want to add a new location - equipment pair into the locations table, then that pair will not exists in the messages table, and therefore the vica-versa trigger logic will prevent the insertion of new rows into the locations table. And you will not be able to add any new rows into the messages table as the foreign key restrictions will prevent that.
